# What is the "ActionRef" element for in Qt Designer *.ui files?

Tags: qt, schema, file-format, qt-designer

According to the [Qt Designer UI file format](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-ui-file-format.html), its file schema supports an element named `ActionRef`, but I can't find any other mentions of it in the docs. My (prosaic) guess is that it probably allows to refer to actions described somewhere else by name - so I wonder what the name visibility rules are?